# How to correctly fetch data from redis in Java Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am having an issue fetching data from redis in my Java spring boot application

I created the following classes

```
public interface ArticlesRepository extends CrudRepository<Articles, String> { 
}

@RedisHash("Articles")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Articles implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private long timestamp;
    private ArticlesData articles;
}

@RedisHash("ArticlesData")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArticlesData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String continuation;
    private ArrayList<ArticleInfo> articles;
}

@RedisHash("ArticleInfo")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArticleInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String linkToArticle;
    private long publishedDate;
}
```

Everything appears to work as expected when I save an instance of Articles

```
Articles articles = new Articles(id, timestamp, articlesData);
articlesRepository.save(articles);
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve that object from redis something weird happens

```
Articles articles = articlesRepository.findOne(redisArticleId);
```

All the fields in the object (id and timestamp) are set correctly except for ArticlesData which always returns null.

```
System.out.println(articles.getId());   ==> WAPCO:
System.out.println(articles.getTimestamp());   ==> 1530049920
System.out.println(articles.getArticles());   ==> null
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?